# Bind button command in listboxItem

Tags: wpf, listbox, command, listboxitem, commandbinding

I want to bind a button command from a listbox item. But my code not work. Can you help me?

My item template definition:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MemberList">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="{DynamicResource appbar_user}" Height="30" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding EMail}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="25" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsDefault="False" Content="X">
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And my listbox declaration:

```
<ListBox Margin="0,0,10,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="_ownersList" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupOwners}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource MemberList}" >
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <EventSetter Event="Button.Click" Handler="Button_Click"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've just copied your code and this worked for me fine.

Comment: I've just copied your code and this worked for me fine. I used it inside the window, where I defined the window DataContext in XAML. But I don't think that this is the problem. Try to use the snoop to figure out what is the real problem with your code. I think that there is an element that handles the button click event. Give to know if you will need help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked fine for me

XAML:

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MemberList">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="{DynamicResource appbar_user}" Height="30" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding EMail}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <Button Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding DataContext.CloseButton,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window, AncestorLevel=1}}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="25" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsDefault="False" Content="X">
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Height="200" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ListBox  Margin="0,0,10,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="_ownersList" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupOwners}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource MemberList}" >
            <!--<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <EventSetter Event="Button.Click" Handler="Button_Click"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>-->
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>
```

ViewModel

```
private ICommand closeButton;       
public ICommand CloseButton
{
    get
    {
        if (this.closeButton == null)
        {
            this.closeButton = new RelayCommand<object>(this.ExecuteCloseButton);
        }

        return this.closeButton;
    }
}

private void ExecuteCloseButton(object err)
{

}
```

Comment: i have try the modification, but not work on my solution. :(

Comment: Change AncestorType=Windows to AncestorType=UserControl

Comment: I have changed by UserControl but nothing. I have no error, but command not execute.

Comment: is data displayed on ListBox?

Comment: Yes data is displayed.

Comment: I implemented a drag and drop system with the listbox, it works. But the command button in my content item does not work.

Comment: I created a simple test project with a window. It work, but i don't know why my current solution not work. How it's possible??? My UserControl's DataContext object is OK! I try to catch with another solution the button click event but no success.

Comment: Does button click on code behind work?iam not saying about mvvm just code behind.?

Comment: Hello I found my problme! :) For drap and drop i have implemented the previemMouseButtonDown handler. And i called the method DoDragDrop in this handler. ERROR => This method put the event has handled and the button can not catch the mouse message. So your solution to binding the command is OK. Thanks.